# Trying to add in line breaks in hex encoding

Tags: python, hex, decode, encode

So I'm trying to convert text to UTF-8 and then hex encode it using python 2, and I'm running into issues trying to simulate line breaks.

I currently have

```
>>> import binascii
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'Testing 1 2 3')
'54657374696e67203120322033'
```

And I'm trying to make

```
Testing 1 2 3
Testing Second Line
```

By using

```
>>> binascii.hexlify(b'Testing 1 2 3\Testing Second Line')
'54657374696e672031203220335c54657374696e67205365636f6e64204c696e65'
```

However, when decoded, there is no line break.

```
54657374696e672031203220335c54657374696e67205365636f6e64204c696e65
```

Decodes to

```
Testing 1 2 3\Testing Second Line
```

How do I simulate a new line when encoding into hex from text after converting to UTF-8?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Should you be using `\n` instead of just \, perhaps?

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks.

Comment: Glad it works! Could you accept my answer I've just posted, then, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should be using \n instead of just \